# Webpack build order

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

I have multiple config objects in my webpack.config, one of these configs is for building 'electron-main', another has 'web' as a target. At the end of the build I want to launch electron-builder to build an executable. Electron application is supposed to use 'web' bundle. Question: is there any way of specifying build order to say that 'electron-main' build should wait until 'web' build is finished? Or, probably, is there any way to execute shell command when all of the builds are finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no way to specify build order.
Finally I've ended up splitting config into several separate config's using Webpack merge + moved call to electron builder to NPM script.